# Return type in case of Callback functions

Tags: c, callback, return-type

I am going through the legacy code of my codebase and I encountered the following piece of code :

```
void *sampleFunction(tUint8 **inParam1, tUint32 inParam2, char *inParam3, tUint32 inParam4, void* inArg1, void* inArg2)
{
    X100 *foo = getFooValue(...);
    return foo;
}
```

Since I cannot post the exact code( since it is work related), I have posted the above sample( which is exactly what it looks like).

`X100` shown here is  a struct which holds some data and there is a callback function as shown below to which it the above function is assigned( or that is what it looks like to me )

```
typedef void* (*tFileReadVerifyCallback)((tUint8 **inParam1, tUint32 inParam2, char *inParam3, tUint32 inParam4, void* inArg1, void* inArg2);

tFileReadVerifyCallback callBack;

//for a certain case :
callBack = sampleFunction;
```

Now, I have the following questions :

1. Why does the `sampleFunction` return `foo` which is of type `X100` ? Is it because the call-backs behave differently ?
2. If so, then my next question would be how these callbacks work/ how does the return value affect it ?

**NOTE : I have tried to provide enough information while trying to keep it minimal. If there is more input needed, please do let me know, I will try to edit it and add more information.**

Comment: A pointer to a function (which your `callBack` variable is) or a function itself doesn't matter. A function is a function is a function, and they are called just the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the `sampleFunction` return `foo` which is of type `X100` ?

No, it returns `foo` which is a `X100 *`, an object pointer. The callback is specified to return `void *`, and all object pointers are convertible to `void *`. The callback is nothing special.

`void *` is commonly used for this sort of type erasure, to allow a function to return "anything". You see it used in callbacks because the intent is to let client code return any object pointer they may like.

Of course, when returning pointers to arbitrary objects an important question that rises is *"when should this object be freed, if at all?"* The answer to that depends on the library that accepts the callback, and how it documents its interaction with it.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you say. However, Is it important to return an object pointer when the return type is a `void *` ?
I was of the notion that like return type `void`, it didn't expect any return value.

Comment: @BlahGuy While `void` all by itself means "nothing", in combination with an asterisk (like `void *`) it means "pointer to anything".

Comment: @BlahGuy - One can indeed think of `void` as the absence of a type. It doesn't contradict the notion of `void *`. It means we have a pointer, but the type information about the object it's pointing at, is absent.